# Using like and % with the name of column in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: Quote, hashtag and user.

As follows:

Table quote

```
Quote                 | user    |  Hashtags
hello world #greet    |  1      |  ,1,3
this is a #quote#this |  2      |  ,2,4
```

Table Hashtag

```
id   | hashtag
1    | greet
2    | quote
3    | hello
4    | this
```

Table user

```
id | username
1  | john
2  | michael
```

What I want to do, is to write an SQL query, using INNER JOIN, to fetch quotes (with username for every quote) using a given hashtag.

For example : I have the hashtag : "#greet" and I want to get the quotes under this hashtag.. I have to do something like this:

```
SELECT
     quo.quote,
     usr.username,
     hash.hashtag
FROM
     quote as quo
INNER JOIN
     user as usr
INNER JOIN
     hashtag as hash
ON
     usr.id=quo.user
AND
     hash.id LIKE '%,quo.hashtags,%'
AND 
     hash.id = :givenHashtag
```

As you can see in the SQL example, I want to check if the hashtag id, is contained in the quote hashtags varchar. using `LIKE '%,x,%'`

The question is that here, I don't know how to use the `%..%` with the name of the column quo.hashtag.

Note that I'm working based on MySQL/PHP

Comment: can you show the format of your desired output?

Comment: Normalize your tables, or use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: @jinCao , I have many quotes with hashtags each, once I search for the hashtag, I want to fetch quotes and users... like twitter do. Example of result : [hello world #greet | john | #greet] when I look for the quotes under the hashtag [greet].

Comment: @MarkBaker how to use FIND_IN_SET() ??

Comment: @SmootQ - How to use FIND_IN_SET()? Read the docs that I linked to in my comment

Comment: thank you @MarkBaker, I mean, FIND_IN_SET() returns the order of the searched item starting by one.

Comment: Do you mean I do something like 
WHERE `FIND_IN_SET(hsh.id,quo.hashtags) > 0` , I'm going to try this

Comment: It works thank you .. I will use it for now, then : I will normalize the tables once I have time. thanks

Comment: Precisely what I meant - the MySQL developers found so many people weren't normalising their database tables, and created the FIND_IN_SET() function for this very purpose

Comment: Yeah, Thank you @MarkBaker ...and that solved my problem, I had the idea of creation an intermediate table.. But I didn't do it because it causes many more joints be used. I already have queries of 3 and 4 joins in the project, more tables means more joins, this is why I saved many values in one column.

Comment: And as my project is very urgent, I will use FIND_IN_SET()... instead of normalising tables and redoing things from scratch again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Never, never, never store multiple values in one column.

Like you see now this will only give you headaches. Normalize your DB. Create a new table that relates hashtags and quotes.

```
quote_tags
-----------
quote_id
hashtag_id
```

Then you can remove the hashtags column from the quote table

Comment: I've got this idea, but It seems that I have to redo many functions and codes in the project :(... yeah, you're write, when I did this... I did it to limit the number of Joins.

Comment: I will use FIND_IN_SET() for now, and I'll normalize the tables once I have time later... +1